# Azure DevOps - Cannot recognize "Get-AzSubscription" in powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have define below pipeline in Azure DevOps to run a Az module powershell in a linux agent.

```
- main

#pool: Default

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: sp-test
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
  displayName: 'Run Powershell'
```

It gave me an error

`Get-AzSubscription : The term 'Get-AzSubscription' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`

The same method works on bash running az command. Is it I need to install any Powershell module first on the linux agent?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the azure powershell command `Get-AzSubscription`, simply use the [Azure PowerShell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops), it is also supported in Linux agent.

If you still want to use Azure CLI Task, you could use [`az account show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_show) command directly, it does the same thing as the powershell command `Get-AzSubscription`.

The reason is that the different tasks will login to azure automatically for you, e.g. for azure powershell task, it will use `Connect-AzAccount` to login; for azure cli task, it will use `az login` to login. It is not recommended to mix them together.

Answer (score -1):

`Get-AzSubscription` is a PowerShell command and you using `AzureCLI@2` task that it's for `az` commands.

You just need to use `AzurePowerShell@5` task:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'sp-test'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: '$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Comment: Thanks, but 2 things here. Can AzurePowerShell@5 run on Linux agent? For my AzureCli@2 task I mark it as pscore scripttype. Can't it be used to run Powershell command?

Comment: It certainly should be able to run powershell commands. But maybe it doesn't let you run commands from the azure powershell module?

Comment: Exactly. I can run normal powershell in the way that I showed, but just not Az powershell. Don't know why